# FreeBsd file sharing option with Mac OS X?

Tags: freebsd, file-sharing

I'm newbie on FreeBSD.

I configured a BSD on VM for Erlang. For private use only, NOT for production service. It was very easy setup and installing, now I can call erl console.

Next, I want to upload my Erlang source file from my Mac into BSD. What kind of file transferring option available and suitable for my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer copying via scp

```
scp /path/to/source/file username@otherbox:/path/to/desired/destination
```

or

```
scp username@otherbox:/path/to/file /path/to/destination
```

Comment: Is it possible batching scp command by passing passphrase as an option?

Comment: It'd be easier yet to use ssh keys; run `ssh-keygen` on the BSD box; then copy the ~/.ssh directory to your home folder on the Mac box.

Comment: Agreed, Chris, but since I he's asking about 'how to copy', I'd give him an answer and a tool now, and he can learn how keys work after he has his files where he needs them.

@Eonil, Look into how SSH keys (and PKI) work.  As Chris mentioned, this will make the scripting easier and eliminate the need to include the password.

Answer (score 1):

sftp is by far the easiest way to transfer a few files from one *nix to another.

On the BSD machine add `sshd_enable="YES"` to `/etc/rc.conf`; if you're not familiar with vi or emacs; this will work `echo 'sshd_enable="YES"' >> /etc/rc.conf`. Then run `/etc/rc.d/sshd start` (or reboot the machine, whatever).

On your Mac, open a console, type `sftp [username]@[BSD_machine's IP]`, enter your password, then `put [filename]`. The file is now in your home directory on the BSD machine. Note: you must have a username besides 'root' to use sftp (add one with `adduser` if you don't have one already) and it must have a password.

Also, if the BSD machine has a file you want; same thing with starting sftp, then use `get [filename]` to transfer it back. Sftp works very much like normal ftp if you're familiar with that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you have a web browser on the BSD installation, might just be to take advantage of the web server in OSX. There's a summary [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/140370/2009/05/pythonserver.html) that ought to help.

You may also consider using NFS. There's a summary [here](http://www.behanna.org/osx/nfs/howto1.html) for that.

I'd suggest the web server method is easier, especially if you have a browser running on the BSD install already and if this is just a case of sending a file one way on odd occasions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only transferring the occasional odd small configuration file, you can use ssh as a pipe. For example, if  `/home/username/foo.conf` existed on your FreeBSD machine, you could type on the OS X machine terminal `ssh <host> '(echo /home/username/foo.conf)' > localfoo.conf`, which should pipe the contents of `foo.conf` to the file `localfoo.conf` on your OS X machine. Of course, replace `<host>` with the IP address or hostname of the machine you'd like to connect to.

To do it the other way, you'll require the ability to ssh into your OS X machine. Really not the best way to transfer *files*, but sufficient enough in a pinch.